# How to enter income from Other sources in ITR

Tags: income-tax, india

I am trying to fill my ITR for 2017-18. My tax deducted on salaried income matches with the TDS1. There is additional tax deducted TDS2, which makes the total tax deducted to be higher than tax payable. If I try to enter the income from other sources in Income details (B3 section of the ITR form) it does not conform to the same tax value. Could anyone help me with this?

Comment: What's an ITR? Where are you located? What exactly do you need help with? Consider reviewing [How do I ask a good question?](https://money.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) in the [help], then to [edit] your question. Note that this site has a broad international audience.

Answer (score 0):

> If I try to enter the income from other sources in Income details (B3 section of the ITR form) it does not conform to the same tax value. Could anyone help me with this?

This will not be same value. The TDS2 is generally deducted at the rate of 10% of the interest paid and is nominal. You would need to pay additional tax.